# How to have @State that is an array with the size that depends on a FetchRequest

Tags: swiftui, property-wrapper

I have an app that is outlined in the following. Most of the code I have adapted from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/how-to-combine-core-data-and-swiftui

But the part I have question about is how to set `@State var isListExpanded: [Bool]` properly. It is an array whose size depends on the result of a FetchRequest (students). Even though the app works initially, but if I tap on "Add" it crashes with the message:
`Fatal error: Index out of range` on this line
`DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isListExpanded[index]) {` which is understandable because the size of array `isListExpanded` is not adjusted to the new size.

```
 // StudentsApp.swift

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

@main
struct StudentsApp: App {
    @StateObject private var dataController = DataController()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            let request: NSFetchRequest<Student> = Student.fetchRequest()
            let students = try? dataController.container.viewContext.fetch(request)
            
            ContentView(isListExpanded: Array(repeating: false, count: students?.count ?? 0))
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, dataController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}

//  DataController.swift

import Foundation
import CoreData

class DataController: ObservableObject {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Students")
    
    init() {
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Core Data failed tp load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

//  ContentView.swift

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var students: FetchedResults<Student>
    @State var isListExpanded: [Bool]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(students.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Section {
                        DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isListExpanded[index]) {
                            Text("Expanded")
                        } label: {
                            Text(students[index].name ?? "Unknown")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button("Add") {
                let firstNames = ["Ginny", "Harry", "Hermione", "Luna", "Ron"]
                let lastNames = ["Granger", "Lovegood", "Potter", "Weasley"]
                let chosenFirstName = firstNames.randomElement()!
                let chosenLastName = lastNames.randomElement()!
                let student = Student(context: moc)
                student.id = UUID()
                student.name = "\(chosenFirstName) \(chosenLastName)"
                try? moc.save()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `Button("Add"){...}` try adding `isListExpanded.append(false)`, or `true` if you want.

Comment: Off topic but it’s a bit strange to have a DisclosureGroup around _every_ row. Anyway I believe this is not so easy to resolve since it not so easy to maintain the array in a correct way and keeping it in sync with the fetch result. For starters you should remove the fetching code from WindowGroup and instead fill the array in `onApppear` in the view. I think you probably need to wrap a student object and the expanded flag in a struct and use that instead in your list.

Comment: I agree that fetch should not happen in the WindowGroup and I only added it so that it works correctly with the correct size of the data on the first load until I figure out the real solution. What is the most important behavior for me to achieve is the size of isListExpanded be the same as number of elements from CoreData. Meaning when I add a new Student in CoreData, if all of isListExpanded has to be set to false that's fine with me. What is important is for its size to be always size of the data. So if there is a solution that can achive that that would be great.

Comment: Regarding the 1st comment from "workingdog", yes, your solution may work in my toy example which I have created to focus around my question. But in my real app the logic for adding to and removing from the CoreData is not as simple as an "Add" button that guarantees just because you pressed add something was added to the CoreData. I need the size of this @State array to be the size of the data from CoreData.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some back and forth with Bard and ChatGPT I came up with this which works fine for now.

I replaced `$isListExpanded[index]` in

```
DisclosureGroup(isExpanded: $isListExpanded[index]) {
    Text("Expanded")
} label: {
    Text(students[index].name ?? "Unknown")
}
```

with

```
Binding(
    get: { self.isListExpanded.indices.contains(index) ? self.isListExpanded[index] : false },
    set: { newValue in
        if newValue {
            while self.isListExpanded.count <= index {
                self.isListExpanded.append(false)
            }
        }
        self.isListExpanded[index] = newValue
    } 
)
```